# How do you calculate the size of a single row in hbase?

Tags: hbase

I am trying to figure out the size of a single row in HBase. I haven't found a way to do it online or through any of the hbase utils and I have used `hbase hfile -mbsf` to find out average row size and other statistics for an Hfile, but I am curious about a single row's size. Has anyone found a way to do this?

Comment: `Cell` has a method `getRowLength()`. Any `Get` operation will return it. Is that what you need?

Comment: interesting...will give that a try. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

worked fine for me to calculate the size of single record
http://prafull-blog.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-calculate-record-size-of-hbase.html

Answer (score 0):

[`Result.getTotalSizeOfCells(Result result)`](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getTotalSizeOfCells-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result-)

```
long size = Result.getTotalSizeOfCells(Result result)
```

Comment: Could you please explain this more?